# How to handle ember-data transaction errors?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I know when a transaction commit fails?

```js
var obj = App.store.findAll(App.Todo).get('firstObject');
var t = App.store.transaction();

t.add(obj);
obj.set('summary','New Summary');
t.commit();
// 403 or 401 is returned from the server (request failed)
a.get('isLoading'); // true
a.get('isError'); // false
```

Use case: I want a user to see that his action (save object) failed.

Comment: have you tried using try catch for the t.commit() statement ?

Comment: try catch will not work -> t.commit() is async -> jquery.ajax()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as of today, ember-data's `RESTAdapter` does not process errors on commit requests.

You may be interested by [the following PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/376) which proposes errors handling support.