# How can i handle http requests failures with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391139/how-to-handle-ember-data-transaction-errors).

Until nothing is done for ember-data failures handling what can i write to patch it, so that i can have a message if my request doesn't have a 200OK response?

I'm looking at ember-data source code, for example, here's the `createRecord` function

```
createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type);
    var adapter = this;
    var data = {};

    data[root] = this.serialize(record, { includeId: true });

    return this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "POST", {
      data: data
    }).then(function(json){
      Ember.run(adapter, 'didCreateRecord', store, type, record, json);
    }, function(xhr) {
      adapter.didError(store, type, record, xhr);
      throw xhr;
    });
  }
```

I expected something like:

```
success: //do something
error: //do something else
```

But there's nothing like this. It's only a `then` after the ajax request.

What should I do? rewrite completely all the methods i need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/204fd3046e9c19b2e7f48f8a929e98df4a00e5b5) ember data now uses promises (specifically the [rsvp implementation](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js)), which replaces the `success:` and `error:` callbacks for a `.then()` style:

```
promise.then(function(value) {
  // success
}, function(value) {
  // failure
});
```

This is very similar to the previous callback style, but follows the promises style.

The first function is called on success and the second function is called on a failure.  Looking at the code you posted shows that `didError()` is called on ajax failure, which is implemented in the adapter.

`didError()` ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L308)) calls `store.recordWasInvalid()` if the status was 422, otherwise it calls `store.recordWasError()` ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1065)).

`store.recordWasInvalid()` and `store.recordWasError()` transition the record into the `isError` or `isValid = false` state and triggers the `becameError()` and `becameInvalid()` events on the record.  You can check these states or subscribe to these events to show your error  message.

Comment: As a heads up, we will be changing how promises are integrated into Ember Data soon. They still will be present but the mechanism will change a bit. We'll make sure to provide a thorough explanation when this happens.